# CMD will be frozen and will not respond anymore when I input character as input

Tags: c

Please help me to fix my code.
CMD will be frozen and will not respond anymore When I entered character as input. I think the problem is `%i` in `scanf("%i",&c);` or `while(loop==0)`.

I know the `c` should be `int` but how can I change my code to a better code. I mean if user enter character, CMD shows the "default" in "switch case"

```
int GetMenuChoice()
{
    int c;
    int loop=0;
    while(loop==0)
    {

        scanf("%i",&c);
        if(c>5 || c<1)
        printf("You did not entered between 1 to5.Try Again\n");
        else
        switch(c) {
            case 1:
               printf("You enterd valid choice 1");
               loop=1;
               break;
            case 2:
               printf("You enterd valid choice 2");
               loop=1;
               break;
            case 3:
               printf("You enterd valid choice 3");
               loop=1;
               break;
            case 4:
               printf("You enterd valid choice 4");
               loop=1;
               break;
            case 5:
               printf("You enterd valid choice 5");
               loop=1;
               break;
            default:
                 printf("You have enterd invalid choice,Try Again\n");
               break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    printf("Welcome To the sorting Program\n\t1)Title\n\t2)Rank\n\t3)Date\n\t4)Stars\n\t5)Like\n\n\n");
    printf("Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5:\n\t");
    GetMenuChoice();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific output are you getting when the cmd window freezes?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. You do not `#include <stdio.h>`, is that the problem? BTW I get a compiler warning *'GetMenuChoice': must return a value.*

Comment: Ah just read it better "when I enter character as input" I suppose you mean a letter, a non-number. Well, that letter will stay in the input and `scanf("%i",&c);` will continually fail until you clear the input buffer. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c). Better still use `fgets` and then `sscanf` and if it fails, dump the input string and get another.

Comment: Thanks for your responds, yes I added <stdio.h>

Comment: The only problem is when I input letter, the code will not respond unless it works good

Comment: I used sscanf too. Same issue. Is there anything like char or int that can accept everything? I think I should use char..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large number of things that *"are just not 'quite' right"*. Let's start with `scanf` where people generally fall into the trap of failing to account for all characters in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) after an invalid entry is made.

To properly use `scanf` you must ***Always check the return!*** Always. `scanf` returns the *match count* representing the number of items successfully converted and assigned, which can be "*fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.*" Further "*`EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.*"

Of most import is understanding "*If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf() returns.*" (leaving all characters from the point of failure to the end-of-line **in the input buffer**)

It is up to you to remove any characters that remain in the input buffer after a failure to prevent endlessly looping over the same character. (therein was your primary problem)

To remove all characters remaining in `stdin` after a failure occurs, you can simply use `getchar()` to read until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered. You can write a simple function e.g.

```
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) 
        c = getchar();
}
```

**Note:** you must only call `empty_stdin` when characters remain to be read, otherwise, `getchar()` will simply block waiting on input....

You can also write `empty_stdin` using a `for` loop, or just use the `for` loop inline, without a function call to `empty_stdin`, it's just a shorter way of doing the same thing, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin()
{
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
}
```

Next, checking the return of `stdin` for the number of successful conversions and assignments means you are looking for a return of `1` to indicate success, anything else indicates failure. However, you must check whether the values is `EOF` indicating an input failure (or the user intentionally canceling input with a <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> (on windoze)). So your code logic will check

```
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1 || (c < 1 || 5 < c)) {
            /* handle error */
            empty_stdin();
        else {
            switch....
        }
```

Next, since your function `GetMenuChoice` is supposed to handle the menu, then have it do the work of presenting the menu. It's rather awkward to have part of the menu displayed in `main` and the other part in `GetMenuChoice`. If you need two functions because you only want to display the list once and then loop over input, create a second function to display the menu which then calls `GetMenuChoice`.

Still further, you need a way of indicating that the user canceled input by generating an `EOF` in the return from `GetMenuChoice`. Since your menu is positive `1-5`, then having the function return `EOF` (or `-1` which is generally used for `EOF`) will allow you to test the return back in `main()` (the calling function) to determine whether to further process the menu choice.

A simple implementation allows you to only process the return if it is in your expected range, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    int choice;

    if ((choice = GetMenuChoice()) != -1)
        printf ("GetMenuChoice returned : %d\n", choice);

    return 0;
}
```

Putting it altogether, you could rearrange your `GetMenuChoice` just a bit and do something similar to the following to address all possible input and only return `1-5` or `-1` on error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin()
{
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
}

int GetMenuChoice()
{
    int c, rtn;

    while (1) {

        printf ("\nWelcome To the sorting Program\n\t1)Title\n\t2)"
                "Rank\n\t3)Date\n\t4)Stars\n\t5)Like\n\n");

        printf ("Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: ");

        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1 || (c < 1 || 5 < c)) {
            c = -1;
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                fprintf (stderr, "input canceled.\n");
                break;
            }
            printf ("You did not entered between 1 to 5. Try Again\n");
            empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }
        else {
            switch (c) {
                case 1:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 1\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 2\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 3\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 4\n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 5\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf ("You should never get here.....\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;;  /* exit loop */
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main (void) {

    int choice;

    if ((choice = GetMenuChoice()) != -1)
        printf ("GetMenuChoice returned : %d\n", choice);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getmenu

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: foo
You did not entered between 1 to 5. Try Again

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: 28
You did not entered between 1 to 5. Try Again

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: 4
You enterd valid choice 4
GetMenuChoice returned : 4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

---

**Reaching the `default` case**

Per your comment, if you need to reach the `default` case in your `switch` statement, then you need to remove the `(c < 1 || 5 < c)` test (which is effectively preventing you from reaching the `default` case.) Think about what you are testing for. Testing the return of `scanf` you are testing for three cases,

1. is the input valid? (e.g., does the return equal the *match-count*)
2. is the return less than the *match-count*? (indicating an *input* or
   *matching* failure)
3. is the return `EOF`?

Your test of `if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1)` covers both (2) and (3) above, so within that `if` block you test `if (rtn == EOF)` to distinguish between (2) and (3).

Your `switch` statement with cases `1 - 5` are making sure `c` is `1 - 5` and if not, the `default` case is serving the same purpose as `(c < 1 || 5 < c)`. So if you want to hit your `default` case instead of testing and excluding `(c < 1 || 5 < c)` before that point in your code, then remove `(c < 1 || 5 < c)`, e.g.

```
int GetMenuChoice()
{
    int c, rtn;

    while (1) {

        printf ("\nWelcome To the sorting Program\n\t1)Title\n\t2)"
                "Rank\n\t3)Date\n\t4)Stars\n\t5)Like\n\n");

        printf ("Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: ");

        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &c)) != 1) {
            c = -1;
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                fprintf (stderr, "input canceled.\n");
                break;
            }
            printf ("You did not enter an integer, try again...\n");
            empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }
        else {
            switch (c) {
                case 1:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 1\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 2\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 3\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 4\n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf ("You enterd valid choice 5\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf ("Invalid choice, integer not between 1 & 5, "
                            "try again....\n");
                    empty_stdin(); /* optional here since %d skips whitespace */
                    continue;
                    break;
            }
            break;;  /* exit loop */
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

**note:** I've changed your error messages to accurately reflect the conditional generating the message. It's not magic, just logic. One of the best ways to work though these type problem is to read [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... (really it listens and really works `:)`

Do you understand the `empty_stdin(); /* optional here since %d skips whitespace */` comment?

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getmenu3

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: foo
You did not enter an integer, try again...

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: 6
Invalid choice, integer not between 1 & 5, try again....

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: 1
You enterd valid choice 1
GetMenuChoice returned : 1
```

Or, of course, when the user cancels input:

```
$ ./bin/getmenu3

Welcome To the sorting Program
        1)Title
        2)Rank
        3)Date
        4)Stars
        5)Like

Please Enter your choice between 1 to 5: input canceled.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.But there is a tiny problem. When I put "foo" as you entered in sample, It needs to show the default in Switch Case:  default:
                    printf ("You should never get here.....\n");
                    break;

Comment: @KiarashMoshar I added a second example showing what was preventing you from reaching the `default` case and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code there is no reason to convert to an integer, you can read the menu alternatives as characters instead.

Some test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/)
{
  char c;
  do
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (!isspace(c)) /* to ignore \n \r and such */
    {
      if ( c >= '1' && c <= '5')
      {
        printf( "alt. %c\n", c);
        /* here you can place your switch or convert to int and return */
        /* int n = c - '0'; */
      }
      else
      {
        printf("invalid option: %c\ntry again 1-5:", c);
      }
    }
  }
  while (c < '1' || c > '5');
  
 return 0;
}
```

or replace the if statement with your switch although I would instead move your handling of the returned value outside that function and do a function specifically to return a valid value.